# SharePoint 2010: Site security

Tags: permissions, security, site-settings, settings

I have Site collection (http://myapp/sites/sitcol) and i have two site in that site collections i.e root site (http://myapp/sites/sitcol/) and site2 (http://myapp/sites/sitcol/site2).
i have two security groups, i want to set security so that group1 has contributor rights on both site and group2 has contributor rights to only site2.
IMPORTANT: when user in group1 access "http://myapp/sites/sitcol" url it should to go to site1 and when user from group2 access "http://myapp/sites/sitcol" url it should go to site2.

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to your question. 
1) If you want to give Group1 contribute access to root site and group2 access to subsite, you can break permissions of subsite and give contribute access to just group b.

2) If you want users visiting root site who are memebers of group2, to be redirected to subsite, one way you can do this is with Delegate Controls. Here is a nice [article](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/custom-page-security-using-sharepoint-delegate-controls) on how to achieve this. In short, the idea is we run some custom code, that validates current user group membership and redirects user if necessary.

Comment: can we do this with OOTB functionality i.e. without custom code.

Comment: I dont think there is anything provided OOB to meet your req 2. You could either do delegate controls or even do httpmodule, but both would require some level of custom code.